# How to set the RequestPreferredConnectionParameters ThroughputOptimized property for a BLE device?

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-runtime

C++, WinRT, VS2017, Win10

I am connecting to a Bluetooth LE Device that will respond with an electrical shock when the command is sent. I notice, however, that there is about a 1 second delay from the time the command is written to the Tx characteristic and the time the electrical shock is actually felt.

At first I was thinking that the connection was being dropped between writes and that the delay was possibly the need for a new connection to be established before the write could take place.  But, IF the `ConnectionStatus()` is actually correct, the device is staying connected.

So, I see that in the `BluetoothLEDevice` class there is a `RequestPreferredConnectionParameters()` method.  I have already created a `BluetoothLEDevice` object (device) and I would think that this would come up in Intellisense but the closest thing that comes up is `device.RequestAccessAsync`.

The docs for `RequestPreferredConnectionParameters` say that there is a `ThroughputOptimized` property that"

> gets a more aggressive set of connection parameters, optimized for
> faster throughput at the expense of power usage.

That SOUNDS like it would speed up my connection and write speeds.  But how do I do that.

Does anyone know how to set this property for a BLE device or even if I am barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I failed to drill down and read the details of `BluetoothLEDevice.RequestPreferredConnectionParameters`.  I see now that it applies to WinRT Build 22000, Build 22621.  In my case I am using NuGet 2017 which has an older version of WinRT.  I'm assuming that NuGet is the way that WinRT is updated.

When I try to update to the more recent NuGet 2.0.22xx I get the traditional 2613 compile errors which may or may not be caused by only one or two problems.  At least this has been my sad experience.

I see that one of the thousands of errors is the  `this co_await expression requires a suitable "await_ready" function` even though it is being used inside of a `winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction` function. In trying to track down this one error I have used the recommended namespaces and included the recommended header files but all of that just got me deeper into the swamp. I have also tried the `fire_and_forget` return type but the error remains.

For now I'm going back to NuGet 2017.  I am trying to keep to VS2017 for now because my main app is fairly large and uses several 3rd party libraries that would all have to be recompiled.  My experience is that when porting to a new VS the gremlins come out of the woodwork and it takes time to squash them all.  I was hoping not to have to do that until I have more free time.

Any suggestions about using NuGet 2.0.22xxx in a VS2017 MFC app would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1** It is not the NuGet that provides the `WinRT Build 22000, Build 22621` but the Windows SDK 10.0.22621.0.  The download says that the SDK is for Win11 but I find that it is usable in Win10.  However, the docs also say that the `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract` is also required.  I now have VS2019, SDK 10.0.22621.0, NuGet CppWinRt 2.0.220608 but the `BluetoothLEDevice.RequestPreferredConnectionParameters` still do not show up.  I do not know if it is because I have Win10 and not Win11 or because I have not exposed the `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract` correctly.  I will have to pose this in another question.

**EDIT 2** **Final Answer** With VS2019, SDK 10.0.22621.0, NuGet CppWinRt 2.0.220608 as mentioned above I went to Project Properties -> C/C++ --> General: Consume Windows Runtime Extension  and set that to Yes. Now the `BluetoothLEDevice.RequestPreferredConnectionParameters` comes up.